# Oracle for Windows: how do I create a new user and login with it?

Tags: oracle, windows

[image]I can connect as sysdba and with the system user, but I am unable to create a new user and connect with it. This is a new Oracle install straight out of the box 19;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2fvl.png)

lsnrctl status:
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))) STATUS of the LISTENER
Alias LISTENER Version TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Start Date 22-FEB-2023 13:15:36 Uptime 1 days 19 hr. 21 min. 33 sec Trace Level off Security ON: Local OS Authentication SNMP OFF Listener Parameter File C:\Users\thham\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\network\admin\listener.ora Listener Log File C:\Oracle\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-53TP1MM\listener\alert\log.xml Listening Endpoints Summary... (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-53TP1MM)(PORT=1521))) (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc))) (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-53TP1MM)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\ORACLE\admin\orcl\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW)) Services Summary... Service "52448234712340b69f274bcc790ecfe0.local.tld" has 1 instance(s). Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s). Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service... Service "bb1938ef0d084b4ea0dc54de32cc23f1.local.tld" has 1 instance(s). Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... Service "orcl.local.tld" has 1 instance(s). Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... Service "orclXDB.local.tld" has 1 instance(s). Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... Service "orclpdb.local.tld" has 1 instance(s). Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... The command completed successfully

Comment: Please post text information as text, not images

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You created a user in the ORCLPDB pluggable database. After that you tried logging in to the root container. Try logging in to the ORCLPDB pluggable database using its service, example:

```
CONNECT COW/CHICKEN@LOCALHOST:1521/ORCLPDB
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm still not getting in:

Comment: SQL> connect COW/CHICKEN@LOCALHOST:1521/ORCLPDB
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

Comment: OracleServiceORCL

Comment: @sqltracy The ORCLPDB pluggable database should have a default service with its name registered in the listener. Can be checked with `lsnrctl status`.

Comment: @sqltracy The domain is included in the service name: `CONNECT COW/CHICKEN@LOCALHOST:1521/ORCLPDB.local.tld`

Comment: SQL> connect COW/CHICKEN@LOCALHOST:1521/ORCLPDB.local.tld
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL>